# multiple inheritance ambigious function

Tags: c++, stl, multiple-inheritance

i am writing an application where in class inherits from vector and qt widget class as well and in one of the questions when i call a function as this->size() compiler is throwing an error

ambigious function call,

i am giving an example.

```
class A:public std::vector<int>,public Qwidget
{
    private :

    public:

      int getSize()
        { return this->size(); }
}
```

i know the problem is because of both vector and q

Comment: far more important question is why you are deriving from `std::vector`. This class is not designed for inheritance.

Comment: you might want to try/subclass [QListWidget](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/QListWidget.html) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly qualify the call to size with the injected base class name that you actually want to refer to.

However, what you do is horribly evil. `std::vector` is not intended to be inherited from (and your code will never compile: it is a template). If you really need a sequence container with signal/slot shenanigans, you should use [QList](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you can force it to be one or the other with `using` to say which:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  void foo() { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B {
  void foo() { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

struct C : A, B {
  using A::foo;
  void bar() {
    foo();
  }
};

int main() {
  C c;
  c.bar();
}
```

Either within the class (applies to all member functions) or within a specific function.

**However** inheriting from `std::vector` is asking for trouble anyway, so in this case the solution would be simply to not inherit from the `vector`.